# Android Scoreloop, OpenFeint etc al

Tags: android, social-networking, scoreloop

I am looking to use one of the social networks in my Android program.

Most important for me is the ability to build a continuous leadership board in which players move up and down depending their wins/loses to others.
The idea is for players to challenge others head-to-head. The winner gains points and the loser loses points.

Equally important, I want this feature to include the possibility to "charge" the player game coins.

Scoreloop includes the possibility of challenges but they are there in order to win coins off other players. In other words, they are the means to the end.
In my case I need it to be the other way around. The "ends" is to be higher in the leadership board and the "means" are to play others with coins.
Scoreloop do have a continuos leadership board but it is not accessible from the program.

I tried looking at OpenFeint but their site is a real mess. It is impossible to understand from there exactly what is and isn't available. 
I signed up and tried to add my program. I ended up adding it four times and cannot delete it!

Comment: I'm using OpenFeint in my game and had no problems implementing it. It's a perfect network for storing your leaderboards, and nevertheless, OpenFeint support might be a good reason for a player to download your game, cause it's very popular.

Comment: Where do I get a good explanation? The site is terrible.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried to find any other tutorials since I've found their explanations clear enough. Maybe you should google to find some, or contact their support with your questions. Anyway, if you have some concrete questions, you can ask it here, I'll try my best to answer them.

Comment: I looked there again and it only supports developers in countries that have full Google market support. Also, I cannot see where they support the purchase of game-coins.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Swarm](http://swarmconnect.com), which provides a similar feature set to the others you mentioned (Scoreloop, OpenFeint), but also specifically includes a virtual goods system (coins), that you could use to have users purchase challenge attempts (which sounds like what you're looking for).  The docs are extremely well written, integration is a snap :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a leaderboard using either OpenFeint or Scoreloop (we started off with Openfeint but quickly moved on to scoreloop - If you want the details, I'll be happy to explain our reasons).

Once its up, make sure its a leadarboard that allows overriding scores with worse scores.

Implement an ELO rating calculator. see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system

Each player starts with a certain score (I use 1500, so that ratings will resemble the chess ratings range).

On a match end, you re-calculate each user's new Elo rating, and post it to the leaderboard.
You end up with a leaderboard that ranks each user according to their skill. i.e. the more they win, the higher their score is.

EDIT: per user request - her are some of the reasons that made us move to Scoreloop:

1. OF documentation looks like it was ported from iOS, and very badly so. For example, the docs gives an example of initializing OF in your Application class. This will cause their "Join / Don't like fun" full screen dialog appear out of the blue, when users are busy using other applications, as android will kill and re-create your application in the background as memory availability change.
2. ScoreLoop automatically creates a "userId" for the user, without them having to register / login. This allowed us to post user's highscores and display their highscores without having to bother the user for logging in.
3. Scoreloop have an "offline" mode, which makes it much more robust, efficient, accurate and easy to use.
4. In flaky network situations, OF login process took a very long time, and affected the game performance. (see #3 above).
5. OF does not allow you to fetch a score rank. If you want to get your user's rank, you have to fetch the complete leaderboard, cycle through it until you find your user's entry. This "solution" pretty much makes this option not-available.
6. Scoreloop provided us with grate support. I've opened several tickets, they all got answered promptly and professionally. These guys rock.

I wrote this code a while back, so there might have been other reasons which I forget.

Comment: Can you comment on why you switched to Scoreloop?